# Can't click button inside view because view height doesn't get changed xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a ScrollView with a `UILabel` an `ImageView` and another view with a `UITextView` and a Button, I download the text that populates the `UITextView` from `json` so I need to recalculate the height of the views and the scrollView programmatically, the problem is that the container view (the one between the scrollView and the content) doesn't get changed even if I recalculate it's frame. I tried with the following code

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, _placeDescription.frame.size.height + _bgView.frame.size.height + _placeImg.frame.size.height);
_scrollingView.frame = newFrame;
```

But if i try to set a background color to the view I see that it's height doesn't get changed, what am I missing?

**EDIT:**
These are the constraint of the view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think if you attach the constraint to your .h file like such:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *textViewConstraint_Height;
```

And then modify the constraint like this:

```
self.textViewConstraint_Height.constant = viewHeight;
```

Where "viewHeight" is whatever height you've calculated, it should work.